# How to get selected checkbox ID from some checkboxes in Laravel 5.2 using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have made a view in laravel 5.2 like this :

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
     <th>Report</th>
     <th>Type</th>
     <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <?php $index = 0; ?>
   @foreach($tableContent as $data)
      <?php $index++; ?>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="reports-[{{$data->id}}]"  id="{{$data->id}}" >{{$data->title}}</input></td>
         <td><b>{{$data->report_type}}</b></td>
         <td>{{$data->created_at}}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach

 </table>
```

And then I want to get the id of checked checkbox in my controller. I have tried to use these code :

```
console.log($("input[name=reports-1]").attr("id"));
console.log($("input[name=reports-1]").val());
```

But those are undefined... Is there a way to get the ID of these checkboxes..?? Thanks in advance :)

I also have tried this :

```
console.log($("input[name=reports-1]").map(function()
                {
                  return  this.id;
             }));
```

But it returns an object, not the checkbox ID

Comment: Is your `$data->id` contains only number?

Comment: iyaps... It contains only number Mr. David.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your code. `name="reports-[{{$data->id}}]"` should be replace as `name="reports-{{$data->id}}"`. In your name value in the checkbox input tag, it includes `[]`. But, there is no `[]` in your `console.log`. Of course, it will return undefined as it will not match with any of your name value in the checkbox input tag.

Comment: Sorry for those typos Mr. David. I have changed it and tried it again.. but it still gives an undefined log... :)

Comment: try to remove `[]` in your input name value.

Comment: Coool... the problem was coming from [],... I don't know why my friend suggested me to use []... >.<